# How to find lost git commits after push?

Tags: git, github

I downloaded a ZIP file of a project commit. After making some changes, I ran the commands:

```
git init
git branch -m main
git remote add origin <url>
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -f origin main
```

After running these commands, all commits that were made before were deleted and this was the only commit in the branch. I tried running

```
git fsck --unreachable
git log
git reflog
```

but I couldn't find the lost commits

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you did but it doesn't sound like a normal way to use Git. It sounds like you forcibly replaced main on the remote (GitHub?) with a single commit. You never had any other commits on your machine, and you destroyed GitHub's commits by pushing with force. Why did you do that? What were you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: The "lost" commits are only available for recovery in a repository that had them before losing them. Your own new repository here never had them, so that's not possible. Luckily for you, GitHub themselves currently keep all commits for all time (due to their implementation of their "GitHub fork" system). However, you'll have to ask GitHub support to restore them for you; you can't do this yourself.

Comment: @torek gave the answer : contact Github support. One extra option is : if you or a colleague of yours has a local clone of that repo, with the "latest state", you/he can push back that state (using `push -f`).

Comment: Do you still have the output of your force-push? It should contain the old commit ID of the branch on the remote side. It would look like this:
`<old commit>..<new commit>  main -> main`
(Using the old commit ID you could try to restore the branch if the commit was not cleaned up on the other side yet)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. We were able to recover the commits by pushing a colleague local repository that had the whole commit history in it

Comment: You mixed up your git commands. There should be either a `git clone` or a `git init` and `git fetch`. Since you missed the fetch you never got anything from the original repo.

Comment: @LukaKrešić I'm glad it worked out for you. If you post a short answer and accept it, other people in similar situations will know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having similar problems, if you download a ZIP file of a repository, it doesn't include the git history. Because of that, when you push your changes, there is no history of any commits before that. If you or a colleague have another version with the history, you can simply push that. If not, the best approach is to contact the Github support and ask them for help as they keep all the commits so they can probably restore it for you but I haven't personally tested this

Comment: "Because of that, when you push your changes, there is no history of any commits before that." Well, only if you use force `-f`. Git tries hard to stop you from doing silly stuff, but if you really want to wipe out all your work, you can.